# Hiearchical Join takes long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, structure

I have a tree hierarchical structure representing my product structure.
 On each product level (6 levels), I have a salesprice linked to it. I am using two tables joined to each other to link the prices on the lower levels with the prices on the level above.
 I want to do this so that I don't take into account a price more than once. This is done with the following code (notice that I use only level 0, 1 and 2 to show the idea):

```
SELECT L0_SALESPRICE
      ,L1_SALESPRICE 
      ,L2_SALESPRICE 

FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM BCT A
JOIN QuotationLine QL ON A.PRICECALCID = QL.PRICECALCID
WHERE A.Levels = 0) AS L0

JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM BCT A
JOIN QuotationLine QL ON A.PRICECALCID = QL.PRICECALCID
WHERE A.Levels = 1) AS L1 ON L0.ItemId = L1.ParentItemId

JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM BCT A
JOIN QuotationLine QL ON A.PRICECALCID = QL.PRICECALCID
WHERE A.Levels = 2) AS L2 ON L1.ItemId = L2.ParentItemId
```

The problem is that the query never finishes executing, and I get an out of memory error.

Table BCT is 750 000 rows and table QuotationLine is 22000 rows.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is taking a long time because of the numbers of rows. Do you really need to get them all?

Comment: Start by pushing out the query plan so we get an idea whether you miss an index etc. Then describe your hardware - something like this is not that hard on a proper mid range server, but on something small - ouch.

Comment: Try using a `CASE` expression with `WHEN A.Levels = 0`, that way you only have to query the tables once. Can you provide some DDL or SQLFiddle?

Comment: Is there a reason to use the ql table? Its columns are not used anywhere

Comment: David - Yes, I need to scan all the rows. I also thought it is because of the nr of rows, but it should be viable...I thought.

Comment: TomTom - I think the server is of the "proper mid range" type since it is not a "home"-environment I am working on. I cannot push out the query plan since the query never finishes execution. It fails after 1 hour of execution...but the purpose of the query plan is to find out how much it cost to scan each table?

Comment: Nicky - could you show me how to use the case in the join? I am kind of new in SQL =)

Comment: Cha - yes, I need to use the QL table, since I will need data from it...

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate how to troubleshoot this issue, here are some sample table definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE [Description]
(
    [DescriptionId] INT IDENTITY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Description] PRIMARY KEY,
    [DescriptionText] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Hierarchy]
(
    [HierarchyId] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_Hierarchy] PRIMARY KEY,
    [ParentHierarchyId] INT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_ParentHierarchyId] REFERENCES [Hierarchy] ([HierarchyId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    [Price] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionId] INT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_Hierarchy_Description] REFERENCES [Description] ([DescriptionId]) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Hierarchy_ParentHierarchyId] ON [Hierarchy]
([ParentHierarchyId]) INCLUDE ([HierarchyId], [Price], [DescriptionId])
GO
```

A naive way to get a hierarchy -- that is, one that is unlikely to solve your performance issue -- might be:

```
;WITH RowEnds AS
(
    SELECT h.[HierarchyId], h.[ParentHierarchyId], h.[Price], h.[DescriptionId], h.[HierarchyId] AS [RowEndHierarchyId], 0 AS [ReverseLevel]
    FROM   [Hierarchy] h
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Hierarchy] i WHERE i.[ParentHierarchyId] = h.[HierarchyId])
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h.[HierarchyId], h.[ParentHierarchyId], h.[Price], h.[DescriptionId], r.[RowEndHierarchyId], r.[ReverseLevel] + 1 AS [ReverseLevel]
    FROM   [Hierarchy] h
    INNER JOIN RowEnds r ON h.[HierarchyId] = r.[ParentHierarchyId]
),
InOrder AS
(
    SELECT r.RowEndHierarchyId, r.[HierarchyId], r.Price, d.DescriptionText, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY r.[RowEndHierarchyId] ORDER BY r.[ReverseLevel] DESC) AS [Level]
    FROM   RowEnds r
    LEFT JOIN [Description] d ON r.DescriptionId = d.DescriptionId
)
SELECT DISTINCT o.RowEndHierarchyId, p.[1] AS Price1, d.[1] AS Description1, p.[2] AS Price2, d.[2] AS Description2, p.[3] AS Price3, d.[3] AS Description3,
       p.[4] AS Price4, d.[4] AS Description4, p.[5] AS Price5, d.[5] AS Description5, p.[6] AS Price6, d.[6] AS Description6,
       p.[7] AS Price7, d.[7] AS Description7
FROM   InOrder o
INNER JOIN
(SELECT projp.RowEndHierarchyId, projp.[Level], projp.[Price]
 FROM   InOrder projp) ppre
 PIVOT (MIN([Price]) FOR [Level] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) p
ON o.RowEndHierarchyId = p.RowEndHierarchyId
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT projd.RowEndHierarchyId, projd.[Level], projd.DescriptionText
 FROM   INOrder projd) dpre
 PIVOT (MIN(DescriptionText) FOR [Level] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) d
ON o.RowEndHierarchyId = d.RowEndHierarchyId
ORDER BY o.RowEndHierarchyId
```

This example, of course, uses a recursive common table expression to get the hierarchy.  Rather than starting at the root of the tree and working toward the leaves, the query takes the opposite approach.  The advantage to doing so is that each row in the output corresponds to a leaf node in the tree.

Performance, however, may still be unsatisfactory with this approach because you have no opportunity to index the common table expressions, whose result sets may be quite large.  Provided that `tempdb` has sufficient space and performance, the following, more-verbose query may improve performance.

```
CREATE TABLE #RowEnd
(
    [RowEndHierarchyId] INT NOT NULL,
    [HierarchyId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ParentHierarchyId] INT NULL,
    [Price] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [DescriptionId] INT NULL,
    [ReverseLevel] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([RowEndHierarchyId], [ReverseLevel] DESC)
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_RowEnd_ParentHierarchyId] ON #RowEnd
([ParentHierarchyId], [RowEndHierarchyId], [ReverseLevel])

CREATE INDEX [IX_RowEnd_ReverseLevel] ON #RowEnd
([ReverseLevel] DESC, [ParentHierarchyId], [RowEndHierarchyId])

INSERT #RowEnd ([HierarchyId], [ParentHierarchyId], [Price], [DescriptionId], [RowEndHierarchyId], [ReverseLevel])
SELECT h.[HierarchyId], h.[ParentHierarchyId], h.[Price], h.[DescriptionId], h.[HierarchyId], 1
FROM   [Hierarchy] h
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Hierarchy] i WHERE i.ParentHierarchyId = h.[HierarchyId])

DECLARE @ReverseLevel INT
SET @ReverseLevel = 0

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #RowEnd re WHERE re.ReverseLevel > @ReverseLevel)
BEGIN
    SET @ReverseLevel = @ReverseLevel + 1
    INSERT #RowEnd ([HierarchyId], [ParentHierarchyId], [Price], [DescriptionId], [RowEndHierarchyId], [ReverseLevel])
    SELECT h.[HierarchyId], h.[ParentHierarchyId], h.[Price], h.[DescriptionId], re.[RowEndHierarchyId], @ReverseLevel + 1
    FROM   [Hierarchy] h
    INNER JOIN #RowEnd re ON re.ParentHierarchyId = h.[HierarchyId] AND re.ReverseLevel = @ReverseLevel
END

CREATE TABLE #Price
(
    RowEndHierarchyId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [1] MONEY NULL,
    [2] MONEY NULL,
    [3] MONEY NULL,
    [4] MONEY NULL,
    [5] MONEY NULL,
    [6] MONEY NULL,
    [7] MONEY NULL
)

INSERT #Price (RowEndHierarchyId, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
SELECT p.RowEndHierarchyId, p.[1], p.[2], p.[3], p.[4], p.[5], p.[6], p.[7]
FROM   (SELECT re.RowEndHierarchyId, re.Price, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY re.RowEndHierarchyId ORDER BY re.ReverseLevel DESC) AS [Level]
        FROM   #RowEnd re) ppre
        PIVOT (MIN([Price]) FOR [Level] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) p

CREATE TABLE #Description
(
    RowEndHierarchyId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [1] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [2] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [3] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [4] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [5] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [6] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [7] NVARCHAR(50) NULL
)

INSERT #Description (RowEndHierarchyId, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
SELECT d.RowEndHierarchyId, d.[1], d.[2], d.[3], d.[4], d.[5], d.[6], d.[7]
FROM   (SELECT re.RowEndHierarchyId, dt.DescriptionText, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY re.RowEndHierarchyId ORDER BY re.ReverseLevel DESC) AS [Level]
        FROM   #RowEnd re
        LEFT JOIN [Description] dt ON re.DescriptionId = dt.DescriptionId) dpre
        PIVOT (MIN([DescriptionText]) FOR [Level] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) d

SELECT p.RowEndHierarchyId,
       p.[1] AS Price1, d.[1] AS Description1,
       p.[2] AS Price2, d.[2] AS Description2,
       p.[3] AS Price3, d.[3] AS Description3,
       p.[4] AS Price4, d.[4] AS Description4,
       p.[5] AS Price5, d.[5] AS Description5,
       p.[6] AS Price6, d.[6] AS Description6,
       p.[7] AS Price7, d.[7] AS Description7
FROM   #Price p
INNER JOIN #Description d ON p.RowEndHierarchyId = d.RowEndHierarchyId
ORDER BY p.RowEndHierarchyId

DROP TABLE #Description
DROP TABLE #Price
DROP TABLE #RowEnd
```

The basic logic of obtaining the hierarchy is similar to the prior version.  Indexing the temp tables in this manner, however, will likely improve query performance considerably.